# Question about spinner interface

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, spinner

I'm trying to make an spinner selection interface like the one in the following.
http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/allRecipies.png

I'm thinking of using rotated UIPickerView to implement it.
Do you think it is possible or is there any other better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These recepies scroll horizontally from left-to-right and back right? Although you can make an `UIPickerView` to work horizontally (see [here](http://isujith.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/horizontal-uipickerview/)). `UIPickerView` is really ment for vertical scrolling.

In this cituation I would really recommend a series of [UIScrollViews](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) that have `pagingEnabled` property set to `YES`.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. But one thing is that I want this spinner can be spin by flick gesture as well, just like the date picker does. In paging UIScrollView, we just can swipe pages one by one, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, you don't have to turn paging on in that case, then it will "spin" or rather slow down like a picker after scroll gesture.